# LUCENE.NET not searching with two AND

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Why does this return 0 results a document exists with TopTabId = 1027 and ContentPlainRemaded = Word?

```
{+TopTabId:1027 +ContentPlainRemaded:Word*}
```

This query is working, but returns more records then needed:

```
{TopTabId:1027 +ContentPlainRemaded:Word*}
```

Not working code is:

```c#
Query query1;
BooleanQuery querySearch = new BooleanQuery()
query1 = ((new QueryParser(VersionsToUse, "TopTabId",      Analyzer)).Parse("1027"));
querySearch.Add(new BooleanClause(query1, Occur.MUST));
query1 = ((new QueryParser(VersionsToUse, "ContentPlainRemaded",  Analyzer)).Parse("WORD"));
querySearch.Add(query1, Occur.MUST);

using (IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(SearchIndexDirectory, true))
{
    var docs = searcher.Search(querySearch, 100);
    .................................
}
```

LUCENE.NET 3.0.3

TopTabID is string type: 
            `ldoc.Add(new Field("TopTabId", doc.TopTabId.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));`

I tried `NumericRangeQuery`, but still return 0 results.

I think problem is not with TopTabId, because and this not working (return 0 result): `{+ContentPlainRemaded:Word* +ContentPlainRemaded:Word*}`

Comment: Can you check your results?  `TopTabId:1027 +ContentPlainRemaded:Word*` getting some results but `+ContentPlainRemaded:Word* +ContentPlainRemaded:Word*` (or the essentially equivalent `+ContentPlainRemaded:Word*`) getting no results doesn't really add up.  Try printing your query before running it to make sure it looks like what you expect.

Comment: Not workig when I added two AND (+) element. They working: `+ContentPlainRemaded:Word*`, `+TopTabId:1027` They not working: `+ContentPlainRemaded:Word* +ContentPlainRemaded:Word*` `+TopTabId:1027 +ContentPlainRemaded:Word*`

Comment: It seems like you aren't accurately explaining what is working and what isn't.  Are you actually saying that `+TopTabId:1027 +ContentPlainRemaded:Word*` gets different results than `+ContentPlainRemaded:Word*, +TopTabId:1027`?  Those are *identical* expressions in lucene query syntax, so it's hard to figure out what you mean.  Have you tried running each query separately (that is, cut the boolean query entirely)?

Comment: Not working this `+TopTabId:1027 +ContentPlainRemaded:Word*` But this shoud be working

Comment: in your "not working" code there's a missing "*" after "WORD".
depending on the anaylzer you're using the case could matter.
rather than using QueryParser just create the appropriate type. ie TermQuery and WildcardQuery

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that "TopTabId" is indexed as a numeric field.  The QueryParse, in general, doesn't handle numeric fields.  You have two options:

- Change TopTabId to a non-numeric field.  This is often the best choice if your field is an id number or something like that.  Something that is more a string of digits, than a real number.  Generally, if you aren't going to sort by it, or perform range queries, it probably doesn't need to be a numeric field.
- Use a [NumericRangeQuery](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d0/db5/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_numeric_range_query_3_01_t_01_4.html) to query on that field:

```c#
    BooleanQuery querySearch = new BooleanQuery()
    Query query1 = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("TopTabId", 1027, 1027, true, true);
    querySearch.Add(new BooleanClause(query1, Occur.MUST));
    Query query2 = new QueryParser(VersionsToUse, "ContentPlainRemaded",  Analyzer).Parse("WORD");
    querySearch.Add(new BooleanClause(query2, Occur.MUST));
```

Comment: I check this tommorow. Today I cant :(